# After flash a new built Android to my device, there is no `Google Play` store app

Tags: android, google-play, android-build

I built the `Master` branch of Android (version 4.2.2).

And I flashed it to my Nexus 7 (fastboot flashall). Everything works well.

However, there is no `Google Play` store app in this new system. Without it, I even couldn't install apps from `Google Play`'s website. (`You haven't accessed the Google Play Store app on your device with this email account`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Play is not part of AOSP Android. Instead, it is part of the GAPPS (Google Apps) package, which you receive after Google has certified your version of Android to be compatible with that version's CTS.

You can get unofficial ZIPs of the GAPPS from forums like XDA and flash them using a custom recovery like ClockwordMod though. The instructions for doing this are also available on XDA.